# I am having issue while implementing sub-resources using JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs, tomcat8

I want to implement Subresource using JAX-RS. The URI of the resource would be like this http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/1/comments.
I am able to get messages using the following URI http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/1 but when I try to get the comments for a message I just get empty curly braces.

Both the resource classes are in the same package. I understand that if the mapping of the URI is incorrect I will get a 404 error but I get 200 status code with empty braces.

```
    @Path("/messages")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageResource {
    MessageService ms = new MessageService();


    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message getMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId) {
        return ms.getMessage(messageId);
    }

    @POST
    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        return ms.addMessage(message);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message updateMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, Message message) {
        message.setId(messageId);
        return ms.updateMessage(message);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public void deleteMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId) {
        ms.removeMessage(messageId);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}/comments")
    public CommentResource getComments() {
        return new CommentResource();
    }

}
```

CommentResource Class Code:

```
public class CommentResource {

private CommentService commentService = new CommentService();

@GET
public String test() {
    return "new sub resource";
}
}
```

Comment: what path are you using in the Comment Resource?  There is no purpose to the private CommentService

Comment: i want to get all the comments for a message like this messages/1/comments.

Comment: if you add a System.out.prinln o log something in test() does it get printed?

Comment: No, it does not get printed.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out that i am using @GET annotation on the getComments() method which is causing the problem. I have removed it and now the code is working fine.

```
@GET
@Path("/{messageId}/comments")
public CommentResource getComments() {
    return new CommentResource();
}
```

Comment: but why would using @get cause any issue. As I see you have still mentioned. Do you mean GET on your CommentResource ?

Comment: @techprat [Sub-resource locators](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2542) don't have http methods. The method simply forwards the call to the `CommentResource`, whose methods _do_ have the Http methods.